# Applying conditions to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a problem applying to return an array after applying a condition.

Here it is,

With a given array: [1, 2, 3]

**Condition 1:** If it is an Odd, should multiply *2.

**Condition 2:** If it is an Even, just return it.

**Expected_Result:** [2, 2, 6]

***Here is my approach;***

```
function oddToEven(array) {

  var evens = [array];

  var odds = [array];


 if (array %2 !== 0){

    array *2;

    return odds;

   } else {

     return evens;

  }

  }

  oddToEven(1,2,3); // returns => [1]
```

I know this is pretty basic,
and surely my approach is all wrong, but this is my very first week learning JS, I hope some of you give me a light on this!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to learning JS! You might want to first see how to just loop through your array and create a new one (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55509889/2950032)). Then, you can use built-in functions like `map`, `forEach` (all the other answers).

Answer (score 3):

Use `.map` to transform one array into another - what is returned from each call of the callback function will be the item in the same index in the new array:

```js
const oddToEven = array => array.map(
  num => num % 2 === 1 ? num * 2 : num
);
console.log(oddToEven([1, 2, 3]))
```

Or, to be more verbose:

```
function oddToEven(array) {
  return array.map(function(num) {
    if (num % 2 === 1) // Odd
      return num * 2;
    else // Even (or not an integer)
      return num;
  }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that every item in the original array is an integer.

Comment: or to be less verbose `array.map(it => it * (it % 2 + 1))` :)

Answer (score 1):

When doing `[array]` you basically wrap the array into another array, you probably don't need `[[1, 2, 3]]`. To copy an array, use `[...array]`, however, do you really need three arrays? Wouldn't it be enough to go over the passed array, and change it according to the rules? For that we have to go over the indices of the array:

```
function oddToEven(array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //...
  }

  return array;
}
```

Now inside that loop, you can get the current element with `array[i]`, and also modify it with `array[i] = ?` ... You can also check if it is even with

```
     if(array[i] % 2 === 0) {
       // todo
     } else {
       // todo
     }
```

Comment: @maaz this is actually [how such questions should be answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32716/feeding-them-vs-teaching-to-fish), yet many people (even with high rep) seem to not understand that principle ...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript we usually use `map`, `filter` and `reduce` to solve this kind of problem in a **functional way**

```js
function oddToEven(array) {
    return array.map(n => (n % 2 === 1 ? n * 2 : n));
}
```

Note that map will crate a new array so your original array will remain the same. Usage:

```js
const originalArray = [1,2,3,4];
const convertedArray = oddToEven(originalArray);
// origianlArray is [1,2,3,4]
// convertedArray is [2,2,6,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `forEach()` loop for that:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var res = [];
arr.forEach(function(val){
  if(val % 2 === 0){
   res.push(val); 
  } else {
   res.push(val*2);
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can modify your own code:

```
 function oddToEven(arr) {

     return arr.map(function(num){
         return num % 2 === 1 ? num * 2 : num
     });

 }

oddToEven([1,2,3]); // here you need to send the array, not 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the array in a function :-

```
     function oddToEven(array) {
      var i;
      var filalOutput = [];
        for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          var x = array [i]
          if(x%2==0)
              filalOutput.push(x);
          else{
              filalOutput.push(x*2);
          }
      }

        return filalOutput
    }
    {
      var array1=[];
      const args = [1, 2, 3];
      array1=oddToEven( args);
      console.log(array1);
    }
```